# ContentDialog's buttons are not shown in a Windows Phone 8.1 app if the BottomAppBar is defined

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to show a ContentDialog on first launch of my app, to show the EULA to the end user.
It seems that if an AppBar is defined in the calling page the two buttons in the dialog are not visible, an empty area with the same size of the command bar area defined in the calling page, is shown instead.
This is the markup on the ContentDialog:

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="MyApp.EulaPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="TERMS OF USE"
PrimaryButtonText="i agree"  
SecondaryButtonText="cancel"
PrimaryButtonClick="OnAgreeButtonClick"
SecondaryButtonClick="OnCancelButtonClick">

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="524" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,2"  >
        <RichTextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" TextAlignment="Left" TextIndent="0"  FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe WP" >
        </RichTextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The GridRowDefinition has a fixed hight, because the text in the RichTextBlock needs to be scrolled.

I have prepared a sample project that can be found [here](https://agenuario.blob.core.windows.net/share/contentdialog1.zip). The zip file contains also a screenshot showing how I see the dialog.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. It works correctly for me. Could you provide a repo/zip to demonstrate the exact problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have solved it by modifying/removing Height/Width and Margins of the Contentdialog

Comment: Thank you, I took the suggestion of Herro Wong on msdn forum where I made the same question.
Please take a look at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/825556d9-1cad-427f-bf77-64c52ec90817/contentdialogs-buttons-are-not-shown-in-a-windows-phone-81-app-if-the-bottomappbar-is-defined?forum=winappswithcsharp)